# Mocking events (event based async pattern) using Moq - how to react to event in UT?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a service that exposes async operation via event driven async pattern.

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoAsync(int param);
    event DoCompleted;
}
```

There is another class that depends on IService service object

```
public class Foo
{
  private IService _service;
  public EventHandler CalculationComplete;
  public void Foo(IService service) {_service = service};
  public int Calculated;
  public void CalculateAsync(int param)
  {
    //Invoke _service.DoAsync(param)
    //(...)
  }
}
```

Basically after calling foo.CalculateAsyc CalculationComplete should notify consumer of calc completion.

The question is how to mock IService when unit testing Foo ? I am using Moq. More specifically how to make unittest wait for CalculationComplete event and react accordingly?

Answer (score 6):

Hard to know what you are trying to test here, so I can't give you a 100% accurate sample. Your sample code seems to be missing quite a few details... I filled some of the missing bits in, but there are more questions.

In any case, a method I use for waiting on events is a semaphore. I like to use AutoResetEvent for this in simple occasions like this.

```
public class Foo
{
  private IService _service;
  public EventHandler CalculationComplete;
  public Foo(IService service) 
  {
    _service = service;
    _service.DoCompleted += (o,e) => 
    {
            Calculated = e.Result;
        if(CalculationComplete != null) { CalculationComplete(this, new EventArgs()); }
    };
  }
  public int Calculated;
  public void CalculateAsync(int param)
  {
    _service.DoAsync(param);
  }
}


public interface IService
{
    void DoAsync(int param);
    event EventHandler<DoResultEventArgs> DoCompleted;
}

public class DoResultEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Result { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void CalculateAsync_CallsService_CalculatedIsPopulated()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IService> sMock = new Mock<IService>();
    sMock.Setup(s => s.DoAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
             .Raises(s => s.DoCompleted += null, new DoResultEventArgs() { Result = 324 });

    Foo foo = new Foo(sMock.Object);

    AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    foo.CalculationComplete += (o,e) => waitHandle.Set();

    //Act
    foo.CalculateAsync(12);
    waitHandle.WaitOne();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsEqual(foo.Calculated, 324);
}
```

Without more information, this is the best I can do. I hope it was what you were looking for.